# Log Sobolev inequality for log concave perturbations of uniform measure

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, pr.probability, inequalities, convex-geometry, convexity

Suppose $\Omega$ is a convex bounded open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (I would be happy with just $\Omega$ as the $n$-dimensional cube). Let $\mu$ be the uniform measure on $\Omega$ and consider the probability $d\nu = \frac{e^{-V}}{Z}d\mu$, where $V$ is a convex function on $\Omega$ (not necessarily bounded).

**Question.** Does $\nu$ admit an a logarithmic Sobolev inequality (LSI) with the same constant as $\mu$?

If $V$ is bounded, then one can deduce an LSI for $\nu$ from an LSI for $\mu$ by Holley-Stroock perturbation. But the constant will, of course, depend on $V$ and likely will behave very badly as $n\rightarrow\infty$.

In a paper of [Bobkov-Ledoux](https://link.springer.com/content/pdf/10.1007/PL00001645.pdf), the authors remark in the last paragraph of Section 1, p. 1131, that their results apply for measures with log-concave densities with respect to $\mu$. But it's unclear to me that $\mu$ can be taken to be the uniform measure of a convex body, which would answer my question (their usage of $\mu$ is somewhat ambiguous to me in the referenced sentence).

Comment: I don't know about comparing to the LSI constant of the uniform measure itself, but for obtaining the LSI itself with a decent constant, one should be able to appeal to the results of https://arxiv.org/abs/1712.01791.